# Spotify — Get access token (for my own user) via Postman

Tags: postman, authorization, spotify, access-token, api-authorization

How can I obtain a **Spotify access token** for my own user, but from Postman ?

I want to **use Postman to fetch the access token from Spotify** (without a preceeding manual log in).

**If that's complicated, I would accept to manually log in** first,
before fetching the token from Postman.

Details:

1. To get an access token (to be used further in my own Postman requests),
   I manually have to get one, while logged in on the Spotify Developer website.

Therefore, I would like to obtain it directy from Postman,
where I could immediately use it further in other requests/tests.

How could this be achieved ?

2. I did define an app on Spotify (so I have the **client_id** and **client_secret**).
3. I also have tried sending the cURL suggested in this [Client Credentials Flow](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/authorization-guide/#client-credentials-flow) (one of the Authorization flows). Unsuccessfully:

   curl -X "POST"
   -H "Authorization: Basic ZjM4ZjAw...WY0MzE="
   -d grant_type=client_credentials
   https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token

Answer (score 2):

Postman actually has all the various types of Spotify auth requests nicely packaged up in an [exportable set of requests](https://www.postman.com/postman/workspace/postman-team-collections/collection/1559645-e1dfc9cb-3de7-4a73-82cd-602334bae284?ctx=documentation).

Came across it while researching the same issue and came across their blog post on [using PKCE instead of implicit OAuth2 flows](https://blog.postman.com/pkce-oauth-how-to/).